# Receiving 'ERROR 1046 (3D000) at line 1: No database selected' when executing linux bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I'm trying to automate the creation of a mysql user with a database and table using Linux bash, but receiving ERROR 1046.

I've looked at various tutorials online, including this website, and from what I can see, my script looks correct!
If i log in to mysql via the command line and run these commands manually, it works!

But if i run the exact same commands in a bash script, it fails. (name of user/db replaced with $1 variable)
Posting this as a last resort as all the posts i have found referring to this error say to use 'use databasename;' but i already do that in the script.

```
#Code to create mysql user with db and table in linux bash.
#to run: ./createmysqldb Testuser1 TestPass1

$1 = Testuser1
$2 = TestPass1

...

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "create user '$1'@'%' identified by '$2';"

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "create database $1_DB;"

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "use $1_DB;"

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "CREATE TABLE persons (id int, name varchar(20), surname varchar(20));"

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON $1_DB.* TO '$1'@'%';"

mysql -u$user -p$password -e "flush privileges;"

...
```

Manually tested this code successfully, so i know it works, not sure if the variables and the use `$1_DB;` is being executed correctly, I expect a new user to be created, with a database containing a persons table.

Comment: Lol... MySQL provides useless error messages. Also see [Incorrect syntax near '@DB_DATABASE_NAME'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/501694/56041) and MySQL [Issue 94398, mysql provides useless error messages](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94398). I think it is some sort of perverted [race to the bottom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_to_the_bottom) to see which tool, like mysql or mariadb or or sqlite, can produce the most useless error message.

Comment: From what I can tell from the links you have posted is that I cannot use a variable as the database name, and my only option is to use prepared statements with MySQL.do you know how how I would re-write my code as a prepared statement?